# Print hash in ruby with indentation for each line

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I am trying to print a hash of strings and integers in ruby in the following format:

```
x = {"abc" => 12,"abcdef" => 44, "sryyy" => 5}
puts x
```

the output should look like:

```
   abc 12  
abcdef 44  
 sryyy 5
```

I can get the max length of each string then indent each line according to that, but is there any easier way to do it? or is there a method that does this already?

Comment: I don't see how; without knowing the max length of a key there's no way to know your indentation level.

Comment: Look at `awesome_print` gem

Comment: Yep, ap might be enough to meet your requirements.

Comment: I have been looking into removing the quotes and arrows in awesome_print but didn't find a way to it

Answer (score 2):

Or to little update @engineersmnky you can do it by this:

```
x = {"abc" => 12,"abcdef" => 44, "sryyy" => 5}
x.each do |key, value|
   p "#{key.rjust(x.keys.max_by(&:length).length)} #{value}"
end

>    abc 12
> abcdef 44
>  sryyy 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this example. I think something as simple as finding the max length and padding using sprintf would be sufficient eg

```
def justified_printing_hash(h)
  max_length = h.keys.max_by(&:length).length
  h.each {|k,v| puts sprintf("%<key>#{max_length}s %<value>d",{key:k,value:v}) }
end
```

Usage as

```
x = {"abc" => 12,"abcdef" => 44, "sryyy" => 5}
justified_printing_hash(x)
   abc 12
abcdef 44
 sryyy 5
#=> {"abc" => 12,"abcdef" => 44, "sryyy" => 5}
```